# Delete message that send by a bot in telegram groups by my bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i want create a telegram bot . It should  join to the group and delete messages in group . Is that possible a telegram bot can remove messages from other bot in group ?

Answer (score 0):

No, a bot can't see messages of another bot and therefore also can't delete them.

> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome
>   loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see
>   messages from other bots regardless of mode.

[Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)